# Silverlight 4 Memory Leaks All Fixed?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, memory-leaks

I can't seem to find anything definitive via Google or searching here.

I know there was a service release for SL4 that supposedly fixed the inline DataTemplate memory leak issue, but I see references after the release data that report memory leak issues.  I can't seem to find an official statement from anyone from Microsoft on the current status of all reported memory leak issues.

Can anyone link to a good source for this kind of information?

Comment: The fact that there are memory leak reports after the release does not mean SL is causing them. In many cases event mishandling and other usage issues may be causing the memory leaks. I do remember reading the DataTemplate issue mentioned in a SL4 document as fixed, but I do not remember the exact link. I will add an answer when I find it, but I thought of commenting in case this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good source for monitoring any bug submissions is [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=silverlight%2b4%2bmemory%2bleak).